# о чём мне скажет MSE и обязательно ли ему верить?

Tags: машинное-обучение

если алгоритм даёт хороший result на cross-validation, обязательно ли он будет также хорошо справляться с реальными данными ?

Comment: я делал проект , и решил закинуть в модель только половину всех параметров (интересно было). А у него хороший result и меня это напрягает . Ибо этих данных явно мало , чтобы сделать хороший prediction , но MSE близкое к нулю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вовсе не обязательно, особенно если обучать на всех данных и потом проверять модель на данных, которые модель уже "видела" при обучении. MSE ([Mean Squared Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error)) при этом может быть очень маленьким, но это ничего не скажет о том как ваша модель будет предсказывать данные, которых она не видела. Модель в этом случае часто оказывается [переобученной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) ([overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)). Эта проблема называется - [`Data Leakage`](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/Leakage)

[Вот еще одна хорошая статья описывающая проблему "утечки данных" и то как с этим бороться](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/)